# Exception error in CStringData GetData() in MFC

Tags: mfc, cstring

In my function, Im assignning one Global CString to varaible declared in header file.But it shows unhandled exception error.
My code

```
CString sReceiceStr = _T("");   //Global variable

void CChatServerDlg::AddMsg( userinfo *udata, CString sIP)
{

sReceiceStr.Format("%s : %s  : %s : %s : %s",udata->cSessionID ,udata->cTraineeName, udata->cPassword, udata->cClientServerMsg, udata->cInsName);


sTempassign = sReceiceStr;   //sTempassign is declared in Headerfile of this dlg class
```

It shows error int he above line. IT shows error in CStringData GetData()

Kindly help me.

Comment: what is the type of sTempassign variable?

Comment: @Anu: elaborate on the error message.

Answer (score 0):

try static cast the data something like,

```
sReceiceStr.Format( _T("%s"), (LPCTSTR)udata->cSessionID);
```